# Navbar tab full text is not showing inside button and how to change navtab row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Navbar tab of bootstrap  and i want to only show nine buttons on one row but all the eighteen buttons are showing in single row with text inside in button being compressed.The full text is not showing which are more in length.I want to change the row after nine button and show the full text. I am not getting the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

 .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(214, 224, 226, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card.hovercard {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.card.hovercard .card-background {
    height: 130px;
}
.card-background img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
    -moz-filter: blur(25px);
    -o-filter: blur(25px);
    -ms-filter: blur(25px);
    filter: blur(25px);
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    min-width: 130%;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info .card-title {
    padding:0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #737373;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.card.hovercard .bottom {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.btn-pref .btn {
    -webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
}


</style>
<body>
   <div class="container">

 <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Sample</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Plot Description</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Ntfp</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Sampling Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Sapling Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Seedling Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Time Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">TOF Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Tree Climb Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Soil Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane  active" id="tab1">C# is also a programming language</div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">D# is also a programming language</div>
</div>



   </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn-pref .btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");   
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution. Add a new `div` close and new `<div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">` after ninth button.

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Sample</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Plot Description</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Ntfp</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Sampling Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Sapling Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Seedling Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Time Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">TOF Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Tree Climb Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Soil Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane  active" id="tab1">C# is also a programming language</div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">D# is also a programming language</div>
      </div>



    </div>
```

Comment: the text is showing in full length but the row didnt changed after 9th button

Comment: did you try the code i have included? check this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/bfm175ps/1/

Comment: happy to help, keep coding :)

Comment: brothers from Nepal :)

Comment: hello brother when i added the long text then the text gets hidden inside the navtab... change any <div> like this bro i am again getting problem      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="hidden-xs">Disturbance Form</div>
            </button>
        </div>

Comment: If you are planning to use longer text, I guess you should try `display:felx`. Check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution. Add a new `div` close and new `<div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">` after ninth button.

```
<div class="container buttoncontainer">
      <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Sample</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Plot Description</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Ntfp</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Sampling Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Sapling Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Seedling Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Time Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">TOF Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Tree Climb Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Soil Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab"> <div class="hidden-xs">Disturbance Form</div> </button> </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="hidden-xs">Stand Form</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane  active" id="tab1">C# is also a programming language</div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">D# is also a programming language</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And add this rule to your css.

```
.buttoncontainer .btn-group {
  display: flex;
  width: auto !important;
}
```